# Rotate of (5x) cards got weird double rotate effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm setting CSS classes with Javascript and CSS3 Transformations (rotate) to make the cards rotate, and when trying to reset the styles after each rotation, it gives me a weird double rotate effect after the 2nd rotation and so forth.

The code that actually does the switching is:

```
currentWidget.addClass('rotatefront');
prevWidget.addClass('rotateback');
```

and the code that messes this up, must be this (resetting all widgets before setting new):

```
$('.rotatefront').removeClass('rotatefront');
$('.rotateback').removeClass('rotateback');
```

since that seems to do another rotation again, and I dont know how to do this a better way.

This is the rotationclasses:

```
#card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    position: relative;
}   
.back, .front {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}   
.front {
}
#card-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;
}   
.rotateback {   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.rotatefront {      
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Link to working JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLhxthkj/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right about the problematic lines of code. It is indeed the following two lines:

```
$('.rotatefront').removeClass('rotatefront');
$('.rotateback').removeClass('rotateback');
```

Reason for the problem is because you are trying to remove `.rotatefront` class from all elements that have that class (and the same with `rotateback` class also). When you remove `rotatefront` or `rotateback` class you are effectively taking away the `transform` applied on it. All elements that have either the `rotatefront` or the `rotateback` class also have either the `front` or the `back` class (and thus have a `transition` property also specified). This `transition` setting is causing the removal of the `transform` is also getting transitioned.

For the first iteration there is no element with `rotatefront` or `rotateback` class. This means nothing was actually getting removed and hence it causes no problems. From the second (and subsequent clicks), you have one element with `rotateback` class (whose class is about to get removed), one or more element with `rotatefront` class (whose class is also about to get removed) and so each of these elements transition from their current state to the future state. This makes it look as though it is causing double rotations but it is actually multiple elements transitioning at the same time.

---

**How to solve this?**

You don't actually have to remove the classes from all elements for your flip effect to work properly. You only need to remove the `rotateback` class from the current widget and add the `rotatefront` class to it like in the below snippet.

```
currentWidget.removeClass('rotateback').addClass('rotatefront');
nextWidget.addClass('rotateback');
```

**How to transition the buttons also along with their boxes?**

You can make the buttons also transition along with their boxes by assigning them the `front` or `back` classes as appropriate.

```js
/* to hide/show transition the buttons */
currentWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
nextWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
```

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.rightnav.front', function() {
  var currentWidget = $(this).parent().parent();
  var nextId = Number($(this).attr('id'));
  var nextWidget = $('#' + nextId + '.widget');
  currentWidget.removeClass('rotateback').addClass('rotatefront');
  nextWidget.addClass('rotateback');
  var nextWidgetLink = nextWidget.find('.rightnav');

  currentWidget.addClass('back').removeClass('rotateback').removeClass('front');
  nextWidget.addClass('front').removeClass('rotatefront').removeClass('back');

  /* to hide/show transition the buttons */
  currentWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
  nextWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.leftnav.front', function() {
  var currentWidget = $(this).parent().parent();
  var prevId = Number($(this).attr('id'));
  var prevWidget = $('#' + prevId + '.widget');
  currentWidget.removeClass('rotateback').addClass('rotatefront');
  prevWidget.addClass('rotateback');
  var prevWidgetLink = prevWidget.find('.rightnav');
  currentWidget.addClass('back').removeClass('rotateback').removeClass('front');
  prevWidget.addClass('front').removeClass('rotatefront').removeClass('back');

  /* to hide/show transition the buttons */
  currentWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
  prevWidget.find('.rightnav, .leftnav').toggleClass('back front');
});
```

```css
#card {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  position: relative;
}
.back,
.front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front {} 
#card-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
}
.rotateback {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.rotatefront {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.widget {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
.widget-head {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e7e5e5;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbbbb;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.widget-head h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 130%;
  color: #00468e;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0.0em 0;
  padding: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.widget-head .rightnav {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 3px;
}
.widget-head .leftnav {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.widget-body {
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.widget-body p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: -1.4em;
}
.widget-body p span {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.widget-body p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.widget-footer {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: #e7e5e5;
  border-top: 1px dashed #bcbbbb;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.widget-footer p {
  color: #6e6e6e;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 85%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0.0em 0;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}
.widget-content-block {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 15px;
}
.widget-content-header {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.rotateback .rightnav[id='0'],
.rotateback .leftnav[id='0'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2" class="widget front">
  <div class="widget-head ">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <div class="leftnav front" style="display:none" id="0">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-left.png" class="slide-left">
    </div>
    <div class="rightnav front" id="3">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-right.png" class="slide-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p><span>Yngres</span><span>Yngres avdeling</span>
    </p>
    <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-footer">
    <p>Les mer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="widget back">
  <div class="widget-head ">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <div class="leftnav back" id="2">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-left.png" class="slide-left">
    </div>
    <div class="rightnav back" id="4">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-right.png" class="slide-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p><span>Jenter Junior</span><span>Jenter mellom 12 og 18 år</span>
    </p>
    <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-footer">
    <p>Les mer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="widget back">
  <div class="widget-head ">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <div class="leftnav back" id="3">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-left.png" class="slide-left">
    </div>
    <div class="rightnav back" id="5">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-right.png" class="slide-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p><span>Herrer Elite</span><span>Elite serie lag for Herrer</span>
    </p>
    <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-footer">
    <p>Les mer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="5" class="widget back">
  <div class="widget-head ">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <div class="leftnav back" id="4">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-left.png" class="slide-left">
    </div>
    <div class="rightnav back" id="0">
      <img src="Content/Images/arrow-button-right.png" class="slide-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-body">
    <p><span>Damer Elite</span><span>Damer Elite Ja...</span>
    </p>
    <p>Bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-footer">
    <p>Les mer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The jQuery code seems very verbose and some of them could be written differently. One of those is doing away the `if{} else{}` loop and adding the below code in CSS to do exactly the same.

```css
.rotateback .rightnav[id = '0'], .rotateback .leftnav[id = '0']{
  display: none;
}
```

I have already made this change in the above snippet but will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Harry!... This has been a trouble for some days now :) Do you also know.... how i can "hide" the clicked buttons when transitioning ? Or... atleast make them transition aswell ? Now they are stuck on the same place and not a part of the transtition :)

Comment: @TerjeNygård: Happy to help :) The buttons are a different thing which would probably need more analysis. I am posting through phone now, don't have access to a computer and so it might be better for you to create a separate question. Also, please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: surely will @Harry :) I will post a note here when the question has been posted as a new one :) allight ? .. Thanx a BUNCH for helping me out!.. very much appreciated.. Not easy to think straight here in 42 + in the shadows from Morocco :)

Comment: @TerjeNygård: I have edited the snippet in my answer to address the buttons also :)

Comment: You @Harry.., are just awsome ! :) Digital beer for you mate :)